# How to make line curved on dynamic angle switch in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, line, uibezierpath

I am creating a maze, I need to move the line that is created on `panGestureRecognized` to adapt to the motion of my finger:

[image]

Code:

```
@IBAction func panGestureRecognized(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       // print("started")
        
        if let scene = self.scene, let view = sender.view {
            
            let location = sender.location(in: view)
            let translation = sender.translation(in: view)
            let velocity = sender.velocity(in: view)

                do {
                            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: beginSound)
                            audioPlayer.play()
                       } catch {
                          // couldn't load file :(
                       }
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(lineShape)
            }
            else if sender.state == .changed {
//                scene.panChanged(location: cameraLocation, translation: cameraTranslation, velocity: cameraVelocity)
                let linePath = UIBezierPath()
                linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 368.0, y: 299.5))
                    linePath.addLine(to: location)

                    lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
            }
            else if sender.state == .ended {
//                scene.panEnded(location: cameraLocation, translation: cameraTranslation, velocity: cameraVelocity)
//                sender.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y:0), in: view)
                lineShape.path = nil
                lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
                
                do {
                    
                            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: failedSound)
                            audioPlayer.play()
                       } catch {
                          // couldn't load file :(
                       }
                
                print("ended")
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I rotate the line to the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a path that follows users finger movement then you need to track locations and build your path with those. A new property needs to be added such as

```
private var gestureLocations: [CGPoint] = []
```

then on change you need to be appending points and redrawing

```
        else if sender.state == .changed {
            gestureLocations.append(location)
            let linePath = UIBezierPath()
            linePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 368.0, y: 299.5))
            gestureLocations.forEach { linePath.addLine(to: $0) }
            lineShape.path = linePath.cgPath
        }
```

end clear points when path should be cleared

```
            lineShape.path = nil
            lineShape.removeFromSuperlayer()
            gestureLocations = []
```

but this will only draw a freeform path. Looking at what you are trying to achieve (drawing a line through maze) you should probably snap those points to some points of interest within your maze. So that user may not draw through walls. But that is another question that will be way too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Matic, thank you for your help, yes I am taking it step by step at the moment, your answer works, however it has something that is ruining the view, kindly if you can check it here: https://im.ge/i/9bwEW

Comment: @mohamad you should probably append the code to initialize your lineShape. Most likely you need to set its fill color to clear or to nil. It looks as next to blue stroke you also have a black fill set. Basically if you try to draw a circle it looks like it will be filled with black color and then stroked with a blue one.

Comment: yup exactly that, fill color to .none, thanks man!